# How to call a function that using canvas ex: function play(ctx){} in IF Statement

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

so I wanted to call a function inside the if statement. :

```
window.onload = function()
{
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function play(ctx)
{
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.fillRect(490,80,100,30);
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.fillText("Play",525,102);
}

 /////this is the part where of IF statement that I want to call the function

    if((X >= 380 && X <= 480) && (Y >= 100 && Y <= 180))
    {
     (function() { play(ctx); });  //this is where I want to put the code

     //play(ctx); when I call the function like this, an error appears

    } 


}
```

about the code, when I click at the object using box that made of html5 canvas, it should call the play(ctx) function that making a play button. the problem is there is no box come out. i've tried to use play(ctx); but an error appears, it says **Uncaught TypeError: play is not a function** . please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Declare **ctx** and **play** outsite of the onload function:

```js
window.onload = init;

var ctx = null;
var canvas = null;

function play(ctx) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(490, 80, 100, 30);
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillText("Play", 525, 102);
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  if ((X >= 380 && X <= 480) && (Y >= 100 && Y <= 180)) {
    play(ctx);
  }
}
```

Comment: does it affect other code like windows.addEventListener ? because in my window.onload = function() { }
I put all the eventListener and other function inside it.

Comment: you cant call local defined functions inside the same function were you defined it. Local functions can be reached with the this keyword. Its better to outsource local functions if they´r not needed inside.